# Protractor browser.executeScript throws Failed: javascript error: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, protractor, execute-script

When running the protractor script below

```
let resultantArr = [];

resultantArr = await browser.executeScript("var elements = document.querySelectorAll('ul[class=\'wbs-droplist-container\'][id*=\'droplist\'] li[class=\'wbs-droplist-item\'][id*=\'droplistitem\']') \
var arr = []; \
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) { \
  arr.push(elements[i].innerText); \
  } \
return arr;")

return resultantArr;
```

I'm getting **Failed: javascript error: missing ) after argument list** error. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Try using ` as instructed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/executeScript also whats up with \ signs?

Comment: @ikiK The backslash `\ ` is a possiblity to continue the string in the next line without actually having a linebreak in the string. When you use the backticks `\`` to span a string over multiple lines, it will have a actual linebreak in it.

Comment: @derpirscher Interesting, thanks, news to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
return await browser.executeScript(`
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll("ul[class='wbs-droplist-container'][id*='droplist'] li[class='wbs-droplist-item'][id*='droplistitem']");
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    arr.push(elements[i].innerText);
  }
  return arr;
`)
```

Answer (score 0):

For creating a multiline string constant you should enclose your string in backticks and not use the backslash within the string. See below code snippet for the differences. `s1` will contain no linebreak, but `s2` will.

```js
const s1 = "foo \
bar"

const s2 = `foo
bar`

console.log(s1);
console.log(s2);
```

Thus when applied to your code snippet, you are actually creating a script like the following

```js
var script = "var elements = document.querySelectorAll('...') \
var arr = []; \
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) { \
  arr.push(elements[i].innerText); \
  } \
return arr;"

console.log(script);
```

which is invalid because you have something like the following in it (note the missing semicolon before the second `var`)

```
var elements = document.querySelector(...)   var arr = [];
```

whereas the following snippet produces a valid script

```js
var script = `var elements = document.querySelectorAll('...')
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  arr.push(elements[i].innerText);
}
return arr;`

console.log(script);
```

because, when you have a linebreak before the next `var` you typically don't need a semicolon.

I'm not really sure, why you get an error about a missing `)`, maybe you have a different script which also fails?. Actually the error from that above script should be

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'var'